# Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, personal-access-token

Even though I create a PET in GitHub, and I set it in Sourcetree, it does get user, or updated.

Cloning a repo will result the same issue. Why? Should I remove the cache, or what?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove credentials, but not from Keychain as they are not stored there, but from filesystem, as written here:

https://eekayonline.medium.com/connecting-mac-sourcetree-with-your-github-account-b6b3bb3c5a66

home directory > Library > Application Support > Sourcetree

Comment: "home directory > Library > Application Support > Sourcetree" doesn't exist

Comment: this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192254/9325884

Answer (score 10):

Right click the repository name in the selection window and choose convert to SSH.

[image: right click repo and select convert to ssh]

Answer (score 1):

Found here answer:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-ignores-github-token-and-throws-403-error/qaq-p/1778978

pen sourcetree, in the right click icon Settings (Repository settings) ->Remotes -> Select Origin and Edit:
Set URL/Path in the following format:  **https://<token>@<git_url>.git**

Comment: This is generally *not* the best way to do it, as it leaves the token in cleartext where anyone can see it, and tokens should be protected in the same way as passwords. Instead, update your macOS Keychain, and/or switch to using ssh.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally a solution that works and does not need 20 minutes of reading lecture.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. You need to generate an access token in GitHub
2. copy it to the clipboard
3. open keychain access and search for github
4. Edit the password for Internet password and Web form password keys and replace the current pw with the access token you generated from GitHub
5. Close and reopen Sourcetree, and try cloning the project again, if pw is requested then enter the access token you have generated.

Source: https://gist.github.com/aeosys/e013268de0e47944abd34d81be13556c